# Searching pdfs in Plone 4 on Mac OS

Tags: plone

I've got Plone 4 running on Mac OS Server 10.6. I'd like to make it possible for the search facility on my Plone site to search for text within the pdf files which are stored there.

I've searched around, but the closest I can find is information about doing this on Plone 3 with Linux.

Please could anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is the same. You need to install the external "pdftohtml" command line utility. In Plone 4 you don't need to do any other configuration in the ZMI or other places. Once the pdftohtml tool is installed new files being uploaded will get their contents indexed. You can go to the catalog in the ZMI to the indexes tab and "reindex" the "SearchableText" index to also cover already uploaded files.

One way to install system packages on Mac is to use MacPorts (http://www.macports.org/install.php). If you use that approach, you can call:

```
$ sudo port install poppler
```

Once that has finished, you should be able to call the tool and see something like:

```
$ pdftohtml -v
pdftohtml version 0.16.5
Copyright 2005-2011 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
```

You might need to add `/opt/local/bin` to the PATH variable of the user running the Plone process.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Plone 3 applies for Plone 4 in the same way.